# How to calculate width and margin using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I made a small function to calculate width along with margin of li but it is giving me error.

```
<head>

<style>

.bill ul{ list-style:none}

.bill ul li{ float:left; width:94px; margin-right:18px}

.bill ul li:last-child { margin-right:0}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function (){

    $('.bill').find('li').each(function (){
            var jn += parseInt($(this).css('margin-right')) + $(this).width();
        })


        alert(jn)


    })


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="bill">
<ul>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>aaa</li>

</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: it is giving me syntax error "var jn += parseInt($(this).css('margin-right')) + $(this).width();" here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring the `jn` variable using the `var` keyword inside the anonymous function passed to `.each()`, meaning that the variable will be scoped inside of that function and not exist outside of it.

Trying to call `alert(jn)` will likely result in `undefined` being alerted, because the `jn` variable isn't visible in the scope of that statement.

In addition, declaring a variable and using the `+=` operator is invalid syntax. The variable has to exist in order for you to add to its value. Try the following:

```
$(function (){
    var jn = 0;

    $('.bill').find('li').each(function (){
        jn += parseInt($(this).css('margin-right')) + $(this).width();
    });

    alert(jn);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

better way to do this is to use jQuery position() http://api.jquery.com/position/